# Visual Force page for records retrieval

Tags: visualforce

i want a vf page that will render all the records through controller and the results will be render as html how please help me with some code and example for custom object.

Class:

```
public with sharing class Active {

    public Active(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }

    public List<Property__c> po { get; set; }

    public Active(){
        po = [SELECT Acceptance_Date__c, Payment_Type__c, Date_Sold__c, Deposit_Manager_Approved__c, 
                     HardMoneyLoanMax__c, Buyer_Name_on_Contract__c ,Address__c, Property_Source__c,
                     Sales_Agent__c 
              FROM Property__c 
              WHERE Property__c.Property_Status__c = 'Active'];
    }
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page renderas="html" standardController="Property__c" 
           extensions="Active" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="Property__c" title="PropertyDetails" >
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Property__c}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.County__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Date_Sold__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.HardMoneyLoanMax__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Notes__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Property_Source__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Sales_Agent__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Date_Sold__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Full_Bonus__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Acceptance_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Deposit_Manager_Approved__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Address__c}"/>  
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange! That is a very broad and non specific question (or combination of questions) which is very hard to answer. Could you be more specific as to which part of this is a challenge to you, and what you've already done or understood yourself so far ?

Comment: my requirement is to display all the records in a single page so i have written vf page and controller for that need some more code

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have ? And .. I would recommend you strongly think about showing ALL records. In due time those could be huge amounts, which will create strong challenges in terms of technical achievability and usability

Comment: added code above

Answer (score 2):

While reading data from the `Property__c` object you don't need to reference this objects name if the WHERE clause:

```
po = [ SELECT  Acceptance_Date__c, ... 
       FROM Property__c 
       WHERE Property_Status__c = 'Active' ];
```

Then at the visualforce page you want to show all records from the `po` list? You need to use `value="{!po}"` in the pageBlockTable then:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!po}" var="p">
        <apex:column value="{!p.County__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!p.Date_Sold__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!p.HardMoneyLoanMax__c}"/>
        ...
```

Comment: if i will use po in place of property it is now retrieving the values

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below line this

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!Property__c}" var="a">
```

with this line

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!po}" var="a">
```

remove this construtor from class

```
public Active(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
}
```

and standard controller attribute from visual force page and as below:

controller="Active" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

Now you can get the records

Comment: it is not retrieving the value i should use output field also or no need

Comment: i edited the answer try out & let me know..

Comment: Thanks sravan now i got but i am not changed anything in controller only vf page changed

Answer (score -3):

My VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" recordSetVar="display" cache="false" extensions="AllOrders" >
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="All Orders in Application">
        <apex:outputPanel id="mypanel">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!display}" var="r">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!r.Id}">{!r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>


                <apex:column headerValue="Vendor" styleClass="ratingClass">
                <apex:outputText value="{!r.VendorDetail__c}" escape="false" />
                 </apex:column>



                <apex:column headerValue="Location">
                 <apex:outputText value="{!r.Location__c}" escape="false" />  </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Area">
                 <apex:outputText value="{!r.Area__c}" escape="false" />  </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Photoprint">
                   <apex:outputText value="{!r.Photoprint__c}" escape="false" />  </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                   <apex:outputText value="{!r.Quantity__c}" escape="false" />    </apex:column>

                <apex:column headervalue="Document print">
                   <apex:outputText value="{!r.Docprint__c}" escape="false" />    </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                  <apex:outputText value="{!r.DocQuantity__c}" escape="false" />    </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class AllOrders {

private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    public AllOrders(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    this.controller=controller;
}

public List<Order__c> display()
{
List<Order__c> po=[select Name,VendorDetail__c,Location__c,Area__c,Photoprint__c,Quantity__c,Docprint__c,DocQuantity__c from Order__c where Location__c = 'Hyderabad' ];

return po;
}
}
```

I can't get the records the way i am expecting, they are not filtered. The page is displaying all the rows. I dodnt understand where i made a mistake...please help me..in this.